# Bash one-liner to display ALL `gsettings` in GUI dialog window

Tags: gnome, bash, gsettings, zenity, yad

Recently I've been encountering many questions in **Ask Ubuntu** that require changing `gsettings` to solve the problem. For example this question: [How to prevent shutdown when one of two batteries is empty?](https://askubuntu.com/q/961278/307523) references a `gsettings` that is new to me:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false
```

Rather than stumble across `gsettings` randomly every week (or so it seems), is there a bash one-liner to dump all the current `gsettings` to `zenity` (or `yad`) so I can scroll through everything?

Comment: Why use Zenity or Yad when you could dump to a text file? `gsettings list-recursively > gsettings_all.txt` Then you could use `sort` for example, or import to LibreOffice Calc as a table.

Comment: @wjandrea LibreOffice Calc is a great program and I love using it. Never thought of it to tell you the truth. Perhaps because of 3 to 14 second load up time and past head-banging-on-the-wall over .CSV import formats decades ago. It wouldn't be a one-liner you can copy and paste into the terminal but you could have a script. I'd be more than happy to upvote an answer based on LibreOffice.

Comment: LibreOffice is just an example. I'm trying to say that plaintext might be more flexible than other options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yad works but not Zenity (yet)

I tried doing this with `zenity` but couldn't figure it out. I managed to make it work with `yad` but after a couple of clock days had to turn to google groups to get help from the yad experts. They fixed my one-liner bash code in 12 hours!

If you don't have `yad` installed already you need to use:

```bash
sudo apt install yad
```

`yad` lets you sort the list by any column in ascending/descending order. You can grab the scroll bar to quickly move up and down the list. The Up/Down arrow, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys navigate as expected.

## The one-liner bash code

Here's the bash one-liner code you can copy and paste into your terminal window:

```bash
gsettings list-recursively | sed 's/  */\n/;s/  */\n/;s/\&/\&amp;/g' | yad --list --title "gsettings" --item-seperator='\n' --width=1800 --height=800 --wrap-width=600 --column=Group --column=Key --column=Setting --no-markup
```

This is for a 1080p display where the screen is 1920 pixels wide. If your screen is smaller, reduce the size of these arguments:

```bash
--width=1800 --height=800 --wrap-width=600
```

## Sample output

When the `yad` scroll box opened I:

- Clicked on the `Group` column heading to sort by group. Otherwise the order is random as `gsettings list-recursively` dumps out the database.
- Scrolled down `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` section.
- Noticed a `gsettings` I've never seen before but might help me solve suspend problems I've encountered (as highlighted in screen shot below)

[image: yad gsettings.png]

## The one-liner pays for itself right away

Here is the new `gsettings` I discovered:

```bash
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor
false
```

The `gsettings` contradicts a `systemd` setting I have:

```bash
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf | grep -i lidswitchdock | grep -vF "#"
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

## dconf-editor a complete GUI application

There is also `dconf-editor` a full blown GUI you can use: [What is dconf, what is its function, and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22313/what-is-dconf-what-is-its-function-and-how-do-i-use-it)

To summarize the link, install it using:

```bash
sudo apt install dconf-tools
```

The whole link is highly recommended reading and it covers `gsettings` in depth as well.